# Define multiple scenarios and validate with multiple scenarios in Yii 2 model

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

In model I have defined multiple scenarios:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['in_quantity'], 'required','on'=>['stockIn']],
        [['out_quantity'], 'required','on'=>['stockOut']],
    ];
}
```

Is it possible to use both scenario `stockIn` and `stockOut` for single model validation?

```
$StockModel->scenario[] = 'stockOut';
$StockModel->scenario[] = 'stockIn';
```

or

```
 $StockModel->scenario = ['stockOut','stockIn'];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't have multiple scenarios for model. But you can have multiple scenarios for rule:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['in_quantity'], 'required', 'on' => ['stockIn', 'stockOut']],
        [['out_quantity'], 'required', 'on' => ['stockIn', 'stockOut']],
    ];
}
```

If you need multiple scenarios for model, it means that you're overusing scenarios feature.

Also note that it is not recommended to use too many scenarios in one model - scenarios work fine for simple cases, but more complicated cases should be handled by separate models for each scenario.

Comment: That is the point - you can't have multiple scenarios at the same time in model. Even if you adjust model to allow multiple scenarios, it is just bad pattern (model no longer controls validation).

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple scenarios this way in model

```
class MyModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'scenario_create';
const SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'scenario_update';


// get scenarios
public function scenarios()
{
     return [
      self::SCENARIO_CREATE      =>  ['user_id', 'name', 'desc', 'published','date_create'],
      self::SCENARIO_UPDATE      =>  ['user_id', 'name', 'desc', 'date_update'],
  ];
}


  public function rules()
  {
          [['user_id'], 'integer'],
          [['name','desc'], 'string', 'max' => 70],
          [['date_create', 'date_update'], 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s'],
      ];
  }
}
```

and you can use this way anywhere

```
public function actionIndex() {
   $model = new MyModel;
   $model->scenario = MyModel::SCENARIO_CREATE;

   if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())){

      if($model->save()){
        // some operations
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: It might be good to add   " $scenarios = parent::scenarios();" to the function

Answer (score 0):

You could if you extend the rule with `when` for server validation:

```
 [
   ['in_quantity'], 
   'required', 
   'when' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->scenario === 'stockIn' || $model->scenario === 'stockOut';
             }
  ]
```

Also if you want to validate in the form (aka client side validation) you could also use the `whenClient` that expect a js function:

```
'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
                    const scenario = $('#stock-scenario').val()
                    return scenario === 'stockIn' || scenario = 'stockOut';
                }"
```

Comment: but i want to initilize multiple scenarios in single model to validate. this is working only for single scenarios initilization at a time

Comment: @ShringirajDewangan A model can only have 1 scenario at a time. You are missusing scenarios, they are not designed for that, you need to create a new model.